# is there anyway to extract numerical values (or equivalently eliminate the text) of CSV so that the numerical values can be used as a regular feature

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

how to clean all numerical features and the target variable price so that they can be used in training algorithms. For instance, host_response_rate feature is in object format containing both numerical values and text.

Comment: Please add some example and work you have done, it will help others to provide better answers

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should elaborate, But from what i understand you want to convert
Object to integer

You could try:

```
df['column'].astype(str).astype(int)
```